# Two-dimensional C array

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm making a four in a row app, or, at least a class which calculates the best moves and stuff. The game board has a height of 6 and a width of 7. I'm not sure if I should name the instance variable `gamePosition[6][7]` or `gamePosition[7][6]`. I know it doesn't matter which one I would use, but is one more common than another? I want to do this the right way right away.

Comment: If you want a mathematician's advice: use X dimension first then Y dimension, so colums * rows, so gamePosition[7][6].

Comment: Height corresponds to number of rows, so I'd prefer `gamePosition[6][7];`. It's **really** unimportant here, though.

Comment: @H2CO3 Huh? Where I studied, the dimensions were given as rows×columns.

Comment: I'm voting to close; the first two answers are contradictory, yet neither is wrong.  The real answer is; it doesn't matter (at least not in this context).

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: It *might* matter, depending on whether you want to treat rows or columns as distinct objects -- which is what I just wrote in my answer.

Comment: Voting to reopen. Even if the answer is "it doesn't matter", it's still a pretty good question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A C 2-dimensional array is simply an array of arrays.

Adding some constants for clarity:

```
#define ROWS 6
#define COLUMNS 7
```

If you want to be able to treat a row as a single object, use:

```
someType gamePosition[ROWS][COLUMNS];
```

so `gamePosition[0]` is a 1-dimensional array representing the first (zeroth) row.

If you want to be able to treat a *column* as a single object, use:

```
someType gamePosition[COLUMNS][ROWS];
```

If you only care about single elements, you can define it either way (of course you have to be consistent).  It's probably a bit more intuitive to treat the board as an array of rows rather than array of columns, but either will work.

Answer (score 2):

Width - first square brackets.
Height - second square brackets.

It doesn't really matter which option you will choose. Your code should be understandable and intuitive to you.

Answer (score 2):

It is entirely up to you. There's no "more common" or "right" way here.

- If you prefer to think of your game board as a Cartesian coordinate plane, then `[column][row]` format will work better, since the established mathematical practice is to specify abscissa first and ordinate second.
- If you prefer to think of it as a matrix, then it becomes the other way around, since the established mathematical practice when indexing a matrix is to put row index first and column index second.

P.S. Of course, the One and Only True Solution for that issue is to write your code is such a way that later you can switch between these two approaches by making one local modification in one place of your code :)

Answer (score 1):

It does not matter for semantics, but there is some hint for performance: when you will iterating through cells on board, do it by firstly incrementing second index and secodly first index. That is:

```
for (i = 0; i < FIRST_SIZE; ++i)
  for (j  = 0; j < SECOND_SIZE; ++j)
    ... process gamePosition[i][j] ...
```

You will win in performance due to cache locality.

So maybe you should plan which index is first depending on your algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

As some post before, it doesn't matter, but it's really IMPORTANT.

**First**. in logical, it DOESN'T affect your code, you feel free to choose one. but in normal thinking, you often write `gamePosition[6][7]` because you often thinking from top to down, from left to right ;)

**Second** I think you need this. that DEPEND how you use this array. I will explain :

two dimensional array just array of array. And, because performance, if you browse all values in array, often from row to row is more effective. For example: you have `a[n][m]`.

You should : (row by row)

```
for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
    for(int j=0; j<m; j++)
        // do some stuff
```

rather than : (column by column) because you will lost performance

```
for(int i=0; i<m; i++)
    for(int j=0;j<n; j++)
        // do some stuff
```

So. you can think in your game, you can think how you use your array:
if you use from top to down more often (tetris game -is an example with my algorithm), you should use `gamePosition[7][6]`

Else, you browse array row by row more often (in most of time), should use `gamePosition[6][7]`

Rarely people know this point. Hope this help ;)

Answer (score 0):

People are expecting high x width and rows x colums, so you should use:

```
gamePosition[6][7]
```

And actually I think it DOES matter. You should use the most intuitive of the two possibilities to not confuse the reader.

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Matrix.html : `An `m x n` matrix consists of `m` rows and `n` columns.